# For greater efficiency while parsing multiple webpages in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

i am new to python. i am using BeautifulSoup4 (python 2.7.11) to extract reviews from multiple webpages.i have stored the multiple links(44 links) in a text file and then pass it as the url needed. the output file will contain all the data i need in a separate file.

mine is the following code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f1=open("udupi.txt","r")
f2=open("Paradise.txt","w+") #reviews of 44 pages
for url in f1:
    soup=BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
    soup.prettify()
    let=soup.find_all("div", class_="entry")
    s1=str(let)
    f2.write(s1)   
f2.close()
f1.close()
```

this code works but it takes a lot of time and i have lot more links to be passed can this be done in a more efficient way ?  Thankyou in advance.

Comment: If you're not bound to the beautifulsoup, you could try a scrapy http://scrapy.org/

Answer (score 0):

It all depends, you could make this multi-threaded..but if you're hitting the same website each time that's not a good idea. It would be like ddos' the site, which of course is rude.

Other than that you could use a database instead of flat files.